Routes with Gmapcontrol of GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation
i am trying to create a route between two points. i did it like that :
var rp = GmapControl.MapProvider as RoutingProvider;
         MapRoute route1 = rp.GetRoute(GmapControl.Markers[0].Position, GmapControl.Markers[1].Position, false, false, 15);
        GMapRoute mRoute = new GMapRoute(route1.Points);
        {
            mRoute.ZIndex = -1;
        }
        GmapControl.Markers.Add(mRoute);
        GmapControl.ZoomAndCenterMarkers(null);

Netherveless, when i zoom on the map, at a certain level the drawing of the road does not stay on the actual road on the map. what i am missing to be able to update the route automatically ?
i could not find any information about it
